# Can I reformat an external hard drive to have the maximum amount space that was previously available?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, external-hard-drive, formatting

I set up my external hard drive that had 1.5TB of space as a recovery drive, and afterwards it showed that I have 32GB of space. Is there any way I can get my space back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which OS are you using, and how exactly did you set it up as a recovery drive? Also, I take it you no longer want to use it for recovery purposes?

If you're using Windows 7 or older, go to `Start / Run / diskmgmt.msc`, right-click and delete all existing partitions on the drive. Then you can create a new simple volume and format as NTFS.

In Windows 8 since there's no Start button any more, just press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to bring up the **Power User Menu** and select **Disk Management**:

[image: 1]

---

If you're using Linux, fire up `GParted` and do the same.

Comment: Using Windows. I used the create a recovery drive setting on windows 8(was trying to get id of it.). Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Just use a small >= 256MB flash drive for [it](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-create-recovery-media-144098) and keep it safe somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the drive and click **Format**

For **File System**, choose **NTFS**

Click **Format**